# Myspace Music Layout Question

Tags: css, layout, myspace

How do I push my content to the top of the page to not cover up the ad, but to cover the menu and myspace links. I want to do something similar to: http://www.myspace.com/sensesfail and [http://www.myspace.com/attackx2](http://www.myspace.com/attackattack). Thanks.

Comment: You know I tagged it non-programming and for the time being I'm sticking by that. Does MySpace have an API? Were you asking how to do this programmatically?

Comment: I think he is looking for CSS techniques

Comment: I was asking how to do this through CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning could work, or you could use negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

without dissecting the html source of the links you provided (because i am much too lazy to do all your work for you), my best guess is that they used absolute positioning (or negative relative positioning) and a high z-index to float their picture over the default banner